# Why is the CSS class being totally ignored?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4.

In my kc.scss file, which is the last one listed in application.scss, I have the following two classes, neither of which appear in any other scss file:

```
.kc-hilite {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  border-color: #000000;
}

.kc-wide {
  width: 150px;
}
```

In my _buttons.html.erb partial, I have the following element:

```
  <input name="commit" class="btn kc-wide kc-hilite" id="report" type="submit" value="Report Issue">
```

kc-wide works fine.  The kc-hilite class is totally being ignored. If I copy it into the partial as a style, it works fine even unmodified.  When it is accessed through the scss file, it doesn't seem to exist.

To debug this, I have tried it as an inline style, as I mentioned.  I also changed its name.  And, I listed it alone as a class in the element.  Nothing made it work.

Looking in DOM Explorer, I see the following:

```
/*media all*/
.kc-wide {
    width: 150px;
}
```

However, there is no entry for kc-hilite at all.

What simple issue am I blindly missing?  Thanks...

Comment: Did you `@import` that `.scss` file?

Comment: Could you see if it this class comes in the compiled CSS file ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand Okay, that appears to be it.  I ran rake assets:clobber and restarted the server and that cleared it up.  However, I don't want the pipeline to precompile my assets in development anyway.  This has burnt me before and it is irritating.  Can you advise me as to why it would do that and what I need to change?  Please post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @Mr_Green  Thanks for your response, but that is why I showed that kc-wide was working.  Thanks...

Comment: @R_G I don't quite understand this question, also because I am not quite frequent with Rails and its asset pipeline. 
Either way I figure that would be another question outside the scope of this one, so I guess you should either edit this one or post a new one. I am sure someone would have an answer for that.

Comment: @AnkurAnand  That's fine.  Even so, post your response as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue would be with the compiled file. Could you check the compiled CSS file, and see if it contains the classes.

Comment: As mentioned above, I clobbered the existing precompiled assets and restarted the server to temporarily solve the problem.  I need to adjust whatever parameters necessary to prevent the pipeline from precompiling assets for development, or at least discover any new or modified assets.  Thanks.